# lucene : how to get a line of occurence of query

Tags: java, search, lucene

I have a number of text files. Each text files have data like this :

`<text> Big data... big data... </text>

<text> another big data </text>

<text> some other data </text>`

now I have to write a code with lucene that could retrieve the entire line when a search query matches,

like if i search for `some data` the entire third line should be filtered.

`<text>  some other data </text>`

---

I've been able to do a little with spanQuery, but that returns me only documents and the word positions. how do i get the "real text" from the text file ?

Kindly give reference materials if available.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652672/displaying-sample-text-from-the-lucene-search-results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. If it's always enough for you to retrieve *only* a single line, then you may want to create one `Document` per line instead of per file.

Then [`IndexReader.document`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#document%28int%29) will retrieve only the line in question. (Mapping back from lines to files will be more complicated, of course.)

Comment: Awesome Idea..  Also, i dont think Mapping back from lines to files will be difficult. I'll have a field in the document which points to the file, That way it is made simple.. 

Please tell me about the performance.. Thanks..

Comment: I did something similar where I indexed email subject headers only. For evaluation, I created sixty indexes of a few thousands Documents, then ran a few hundred queries per index. That took about half a minute *in total*, including loading time for the Java VM and several libraries. Performance depends on a lot of factors of course, so YMMV.