# Should I use Lucene just for Highlighting?

Tags: java, lucene

I have an application that searches text indexed in a MSSQL database.  My current search functionality works fine.  I just need to display the search results with the surrounding text of the search terms (like google does).  The only tool I could find to do this is Lucene's text highlighting.  I read about it from this question: [Displaying sample text from the Lucene Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652672/displaying-sample-text-from-the-lucene-search-results).  I haven't looked into Lucene for very long, but I'm guessing I'd have to create documents for each search hit.

I was wondering if what I want to do is even possible with Lucene, and whether it'd be overkill to use a tool like this for my purpose.  Are there any other tools I could/should use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the size of the text you are trying to highlight, but if it is rather small, you could use Lucene highlighting functionality on top of your search backend. See [Highlighter](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html) documentation for more information.

In case this would not be fast enough for you (if you want to highlight large chunks ot text for example), Lucene can make highlighting faster by using [term vectors](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_1_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.TermVector.html), but this would require you to move your backend from MSSQL to Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

It would be overkill&: Lucene is a complete search/indexing engine with stemming, scoring, and other stuff. It's likely *better* than what you're doing, but it depends on your goals.

If you're just doing simple keyword highlighting, consider a regex to insert highlighting tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you *already can get surrounding text* of the found keywords, and this is really *the only thing you need*, then yes, Lucene is an overkill - just **surround your keywords with highlighting tags**. However, in most cases

But in most cases as times goes people start thinking of other advanced options, such as *stemming* (if you search for "highlight" you also find "highlighting" and "highlighter"), *synonym* search, *language detection*, etc. If you ever thought you may need such things, or even you haven't ready algorithm to find text snippets with keywords (surrounding text), I highly recommend you **diving into Lucene** world. The best option I can think of is to index all your text fields from MSSQL and base all your text search on Lucene.

If you are afraid of hard Lucene coding, you may use [**Solr**](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) - Lucene-based web server with extremely wide range of capabilities, easily configured with XML-files. Solr has both - simple web and a number of programming interfaces ([Solrj](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj) for Java).

Comment: Well the only problem with coding this logic myself is I'm doing SQL index queries with ContainsTable and FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, xxx) and I believe that's more advanced than simply finding keywords with a regular expression.  I guess I really should be using the same logic I use to perform the search as I am for highlighting.  I was also hoping I didn't have to code the functionality to create the actual summary string.  I really can't invest too much time in this as it is so that's why I was looking for some API to do this for me.

Comment: That's why I said that most probably you need Lucene - `FORMSOF` is very similar to stemming in Lucene, but `FORMSOF` doesn't provide you with highlighting, and Lucene does.